# Select from table if record found in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to select some rows from Table 1 lets say if a value is found in Table 2. So I want to check if the value (I will enter the value from command line) is found in Table 2 and then select rows from Table1, if not I want to select rows from another table. 
I tried CASE but from what I got that works only if you want to check for value within one table. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
-- If value is found in table2, select from table1
select * -- <- use padding if necessary 
  from table1
 where exists (select 1
                 from table2
                where myField = value)

union all

-- If value is not found in table2, select from another_Table
select * -- <- use padding if necessary
  from another_Table
 where not exists (select 1
                     from table2
                    where myField = value)
```

Comment: Thank you but what to do if the tables have different number and /or types of columns?

Comment: @Albano Vito: use padding (add nulls), cast, e.g.: select id, null, comments ... union all select id, name, null

Comment: Beware! Where Exists is is very slow query because it will run whole tables scan for every row!! it took 19 seconds when I tested it, in comparison Left join is much much faster it took only 0.85 seconds.

Comment: @DeepBlue: it depends on existing indexes, RDBMS, statistics collected etc.

Answer (score 1):

This query will select from `Table1` if `:id` exists in `Table3`, and from `Table2` otherwise:

```
select  *
from    Table1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table3
        where   id = :id
        )
union all
select  *
from    Table2
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table3
        where   id = :id
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but Table1 and Table2 do not have the same column number or types. I want to select one of them independently.