# Select records from one table where a column value exists in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 2 MySQL tables A and B.

I would like to select only the records from B where a certain value exists in A.

Example:

A has columns: aID, Name

B has columns: bID, aID, Name

I just want the records from B for which aID exists in A.

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to use a join.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select from table if record found in another table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310838/select-from-table-if-record-found-in-another-table)

Answer (score 7):

You need to do either INNER JOIN - records that exists in both tables, or use LEFT join, to show records that exists in A and matching IDs exists in B

A good reference:

[image: joins]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a join, and if you don't want to retrieve anything from table b, just return values from table a.

This should work

`select b.* from b join a on b.aID=a.aID`

Answer (score 1):

Below query will also work and will be effective

```
SELECT * FROM B 
WHERE B.aID IN (SELECT DISTINCT aID FROM A)
```

Comment: This will work, but inefficiently. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple inner join between tables A and B. Since they are related on the aID column, you can use that to join them together:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a ON a.aID = b.aID;
```

This will only select rows in which the aID value from tableB exists in tableA. If there is no connection, the rows can't be included in the join.

While I recommend using a join, you can also replace it with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableB
WHERE aID NOT IN (SELECT aID FROM tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like this.

```
Select b.col1,b.col2... From tableB b inner join table tableA a on b.field = a.field
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT b.* FROM tableB b LEFT JOIN tableA a ON b.aID = a.aID
```

Comment: A left join will not work. This will include ALL rows from B, regardless of whether or not it has a connection with table A.

Comment: This will work actually. Isn't b.aID = a.aID used to check if aID from table B exists in A? How quick of you to downvote an answer.

Comment: because it's a left join, so all rows from B are returned. If a row in b does not have b.aid = a.aid, it is still returned in this query.