# Pivot table columns to rows and use a value in one table if it does not exists in another

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, mariadb, exists

I'd like to create a report from tables that don't have an ideal layout. I can create pivot tables in excel but I want to create the reports online for a web based dashboard.  I've looked at
http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf for pivot tables and [Select from table if record found in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310838/select-from-table-if-record-found-in-another-table) for determining if a value exists but I cannot get the desired results. I was able to create a pivot table with a temp table in mysql but the reporting software would not allow data manipulation.

Some answers (qid 742) are in the survey_survey_144477 table but others are in the answers table. So I tried to use the value from survey_survey_144477 if the qid did nto exist in survey_answers.

This is only for one specific report. The survey results are in table survey_survey_144477 and only have a few questions but other surveys may have 20 or 30 questions.  So, I'd liek to make this dynmaic so I won't have to change all of the column heading for every report.  I also looked for parsing the column because part of the columns in survey_survey_144477 have the qid but no luck.  I also treied to determine how I could select all of the colums but disregard some such as token, last page, etc. because I thought it would be helpful if I made it dynamic but also no luck.

I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

The desired output would be:

```
| How would you rate ... | Do you think our product ... | One a scale of 1-10 ... | Will you recommend |
+-----------------+------+------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Excellent              | Yes                          | 7                       | Yes                |
| Very good              | No                           | 8                       | Yes                |
```

I have tried:

```
## Create pivot table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
SELECT id,'144477X148X740' AS lid, 740 AS qid, 144477X148X740 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id, '144477X148X741' AS lid, 741 AS qid, 144477X148X741 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id, '144477X148X742SQ001' AS lid, 742 AS qid, 144477X148X742SQ001 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id, '144477X148X745' AS lid, 745 AS qid, 144477X148X745 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477;


## Get the answers.  Table survey_answers has answers from dropdowns and selection boxes.
## Other answers are in the temp table.
select T.id, SQ.question, SA.answer
   from survey_questions SQ
   join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
   join temp T on T.qid = SQ.qid
   where SQ.sid = 144477
   --   and exists (select SA.answer as answer
   --                      from survey_answers SA
   --                     join survey_questions SQ on SA.qid = SQ.qid
   --                     join temp T on T.qid = SQ.qid)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2
select id, qid, value
   from temp
   where not exists (select qid from survey_answers
                           where temp.qid = survey_answers.qid);



    describe survey_survey_144477;
    +---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field               | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                  | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | token               | varchar(35)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | submitdate          | datetime       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | lastpage            | int(11)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | startlanguage       | varchar(20)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | ipaddr              | text           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | refurl              | text           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | 144477X148X740      | varchar(5)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | 144477X148X741      | varchar(5)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | 144477X148X742SQ001 | decimal(30,10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | 144477X148X745      | varchar(5)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | 144477X148X748      | text           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    describe survey_questions ;
    +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | qid            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | parent_qid     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
    | sid            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
    | gid            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
    | type           | varchar(1)   | NO   | MUL | T       |                |
    | title          | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |         |                |
    | question       | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | preg           | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | help           | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | other          | varchar(1)   | NO   |     | N       |                |
    | mandatory      | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | question_order | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | language       | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | en      |                |
    | scale_id       | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | same_default   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
    | relevance      | mediumtext   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | modulename     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    describe survey_answers ;
    +------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field            | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | qid              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
    | code             | varchar(5)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
    | answer           | mediumtext  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | sortorder        | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
    | assessment_value | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
    | language         | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | en      |       |
    | scale_id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
    +------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

    select id, 144477X148X740, 144477X148X741, 144477X148X742SQ001, 144477X148X745, 144477X148X748 from survey_survey_144477 limit 10;
    +----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
    | id | 144477X148X740 | 144477X148X741 | 144477X148X742SQ001 | 144477X148X745 | 144477X148X748 |
    +----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
    |  1 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  2 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  3 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  4 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  5 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  6 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  7 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  8 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    |  9 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    | 10 | 1              | A2             |        5.0000000000 | A2             | name@email.com |
    +----+----------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------+

select qid, sid, question from survey_questions where sid = 144477;
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| qid | sid    | question                                                                                  |
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 748 | 144477 | Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you. |
| 740 | 144477 | How would you rate our product's quality?                                                 |
| 741 | 144477 | Do you think our product helps your business?                                             |
| 742 | 144477 | One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?                         |
| 743 | 144477 |                                                                                           |
| 745 | 144477 | Will you recommend our product?                                                           |
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

select * from survey_answers where qid between 740 and 745;
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
| qid | code | answer    | sortorder | assessment_value | language | scale_id |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
| 740 | 1    | Excellent |         1 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 2    | Very good |         2 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 3    | Good      |         3 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 4    | Fair      |         4 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 5    | Poor      |         5 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 741 | A1   | Yes       |         1 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 741 | A2   | No        |         2 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 745 | A1   | Yes       |         1 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 745 | A2   | No        |         2 |                0 | en       |        0 |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Update:

I created a table to map values from one table to another. Automating this will be a challenge that I will mention later.

```
CREATE TABLE `survey_answers_lookup` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `survey_table_row_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'id that is in the survey_<id> table',
  `answer` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,740,1,1);

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,741,1,'A1');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,742,1,'5.0000000000');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,745,1,'A1');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,748,1,'1@email.com');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup(sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,740,2,'2');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,741,2,'A2');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,742,2,'8.0000000000');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup(sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,745,2,'A2');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup(sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,748,2,'2@email.com');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,740,3,'5');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,741,3,'A2');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,742,3,'10.0000000000');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup (sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,745,3,'A2');

INSERT INTO survey_answers_lookup(sid,qid,survey_table_row_id,answer)
VALUES (144477,748,3,'3@email.com');
```

Which results in

```
select * from survey_answers_lookup;

# id, sid, qid, survey_table_row_id, answer
'1', '144477', '740', '1', '1'
'2', '144477', '741', '1', 'A1'
'3', '144477', '742', '1', '5.0000000000'
'4', '144477', '745', '1', 'A1'
'5', '144477', '748', '1', '1@email.com'
'6', '144477', '740', '2', '2'
'7', '144477', '741', '2', 'A2'
'8', '144477', '742', '2', '8.0000000000'
'9', '144477', '745', '2', 'A2'
'10', '144477', '748', '2', '2@email.com'
'11', '144477', '740', '3', '5'
'12', '144477', '741', '3', 'A2'
'13', '144477', '742', '3', '10.0000000000'
'14', '144477', '745', '3', 'A2'
'15', '144477', '748', '3', '3@email.com'
```

Attempts to get the questions and answers.

```
 -- Gives all of the rows from the answers_table even if that is not in the 
 -- survey_answers_lookup table because of the left join.  740 should only be printed three times.
    select
        --SQ.qid,
        SA.code,
        SQ.question,
        SQ.type,
        -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
        if (SQ.type IN ('B','M','L'), SA.answer, LU2.answer) as 'answer'
        from survey_questions SQ
           left join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
              -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
           left join survey_answers_lookup LU on LU.qid = SQ.qid 
               and LU.answer = SA.code
              -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
           left join survey_answers_lookup LU2 on LU2.qid = SQ.qid 
                and SQ.title = 'Q7'
      where SQ.sid = 144477;

# --SQ.qid, code, question, type, answer
'740', '1', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'L', 'Excellent'
'740', '2', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'L', 'Very good'
'740', '5', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'L', 'Poor'
'740', '3', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'L', 'Good'
'740', '4', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'L', 'Fair'
'741', 'A1', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'L', 'Yes'
'741', 'A2', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'L', 'No'
'741', 'A2', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'L', 'No'
'742', NULL, 'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', 'K', NULL
'745', 'A1', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'L', 'Yes'
'745', 'A2', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'L', 'No'
'745', 'A2', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'L', 'No'
'748', NULL, 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', 'S', '1@email.com'
'748', NULL, 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', 'S', '2@email.com'
'748', NULL, 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', 'S', '3@email.com'
```

-- Returns more than one row

```
  select
    SQ.qid,
    SQ.question,
    SQ.type,
    -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (SQ.type IN ('B','M','L'), 
        (select SA.answer
           from survey_answers SA 
              join survey_questions SQ2 on SQ2.qid = SA.qid
              join survey_answers_lookup LU on LU.qid = SQ2.qid 
                 and LU.answer = SA.code),
          (select LU2.answer 
              from survey_answers_lookup LU2 
              join survey_questions SQ3 on SQ3.qid = LU2.qid)         
     ) as answer
      from survey_questions SQ        
      where SQ.sid = 144477;
```

This works if the types are 'B','M','L'.

```
   select
    -- qid,
    -- SA.code,
    question,
    -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (type IN ('B','M','L'), 
        (select answer
           from survey_answers
              where survey_questions.qid = survey_answers.qid
              and survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid 
              and survey_answers_lookup.answer = survey_answers.code
         ),
         (0 -- select answer 
            --  from survey_answers_lookup 
             --  where survey_questions.qid = survey_answers_lookup.qid
          )         
     ) as answer
      from survey_questions 
      join survey_answers_lookup on survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid
      where survey_questions.sid = 144477;

'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'Yes'
'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'No'
'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'No'
'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Excellent'
'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Very good'
'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Poor'
'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '0'
'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '0'
'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '0'
'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '0'
'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '0'
'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '0'
'Will you recommend our product?', 'Yes'
'Will you recommend our product?', 'No'
'Will you recommend our product?', 'No'
```

-- Error: Subquery returns more than one row.

```
  select
-- qid,
-- SA.code,
question,
-- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
if (type IN ('B','M','L'), 
    (select answer
       from survey_answers
          where survey_questions.qid = survey_answers.qid
          and survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid 
          and survey_answers_lookup.answer = survey_answers.code
     ),
     (select answer 
         from survey_answers_lookup
          join survey_questions on survey_questions.qid = survey_answers_lookup.qid
              where not exists (select * -- if the value is not in survey_answers table (not exists)
                                 from survey_answers
                                    where survey_answers.qid = survey_answers_lookup.qid
                                       LIMIT 1
                              )
      )         
 ) as answer
  from survey_questions 
  join survey_answers_lookup on survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid
  where survey_questions.sid = 144477;

-- ----------------
-- ----------------

      select
      -- survey_answers_lookup.survey_table_row_id,
    -- qid,
    -- SA.code,
    question,
    -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (type IN ('B','M','L'), 
        (select answer
           from survey_answers
              where survey_questions.qid = survey_answers.qid
              and survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid 
              and survey_answers_lookup.answer = survey_answers.code
         ),
         (select answer 
             from survey_answers_lookup
                 where qid not in (select qid  
                                     from survey_answers
                                  )
          )         
     ) as answer
      from survey_questions 
      join survey_answers_lookup on survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid
      where survey_questions.sid = 144477;
```

The idea is to get the answers from table survey_answers if the types are 'B','M','L' and to get the answers from table survey_answers_lookup if they are another type.  The qid is not in table survey_answers if the answers is not in that table. Table survey_answers_lookup has three answers for qid's 742 and 748 and the query does not know which value to get.  I guess I need to add another value to join it. Thanks

```
select answer, qid
             from survey_answers_lookup
                  where qid not in (select qid from survey_answers)

# answer, qid
'5.0000000000', '742'
'1@email.com', '748'
'8.0000000000', '742'
'2@email.com', '748'
'10.0000000000', '742'
'3@email.com', '748'
```

It might be messy but maybe I can add a counter and then compare the counter to the id in table survey_answers_lookup?

```
select answer
             from survey_answers_lookup
                  where qid not in (select qid from survey_answers)
                  and id = @counter
```

I think I got it to work.

```
set @counter = 0;

  select
     @counter := @counter+1 AS newindex,
      survey_answers_lookup.id as id,
      survey_answers_lookup.survey_table_row_id,
      survey_answers_lookup.qid,
      question,
    -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (type IN ('B','M','L'), 
        (select answer
           from survey_answers
              where survey_questions.qid = survey_answers.qid
              and survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid 
              and survey_answers_lookup.answer = survey_answers.code
         ),
         (select answer
             from survey_answers_lookup
                  where qid not in (select qid from survey_answers)
                  and id = @counter
          )      
     ) as answer
      from survey_questions 
      join survey_answers_lookup on survey_answers_lookup.qid = survey_questions.qid
      where survey_questions.sid = 144477
      order by survey_answers_lookup.id;

# newindex, id, survey_table_row_id, qid, question, answer
'1', '1', '1', '740', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Excellent'
'2', '2', '1', '741', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'Yes'
'3', '3', '1', '742', 'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '5.0000000000'
'4', '4', '1', '745', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'Yes'
'5', '5', '1', '748', 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '1@email.com'
'6', '6', '2', '740', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Very good'
'7', '7', '2', '741', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'No'
'8', '8', '2', '742', 'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '8.0000000000'
'9', '9', '2', '745', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'No'
'10', '10', '2', '748', 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '2@email.com'
'11', '11', '3', '740', 'How would you rate our product\'s quality?', 'Poor'
'12', '12', '3', '741', 'Do you think our product helps your business?', 'No'
'13', '13', '3', '742', 'One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?', '10.0000000000'
'14', '14', '3', '745', 'Will you recommend our product?', 'No'
'15', '15', '3', '748', 'Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you.', '3@email.com'
```

Now I need to create a trigger that updates this table when a new survey is created and questions are answered.

(from comments)

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  survey_survey_144477
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  id, 
        144477X148X741,
        741 AS qid,
        144477X148X741 AS value
     FROM  survey_survey_144477
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  id,
        144477X148X742SQ001,
        742 AS qid,
        144477X148X742SQ001 AS value
     FROM  survey_survey_144477
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  id,
        144477X148X745, 745 AS qid,
        144477X148X745 AS value
     FROM  survey_survey_144477;

select  T.id, SQ.question, SQ.type, -- SA.answer,
        case SQ.type
            when 'L' then SA.answer -- list choice --
            when 'M' then -- multiple choice --
            when 'B' then -- array-10(B)
            when 'T' OR  'N'  then T.value -- text or  numeric
            when 'K' then T.value -- slider --
            else "Do nothing" end as 'answer'
    from  survey_questions SQ
    join  survey_answers SA  ON SA.qid = SQ.qid
    join  temp T  ON T.qid = SQ.qid  and  T.value = SA.code
    where  SQ.sid = 144477 --
      and  SQ.type = 'K'
    order by  T.id;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Thanks Rick,  I tried a left join.  I would post the code but I don't see a reply option on this thread.  I only see a comment option.   I tried the code at this link but I could not get it to work after a while of debugging.  http://olihb.com/2010/07/31/using-crystal-reports-with-limesurvey/   I'm attempting to create stored procedures from that code but I got collation errors.  So I updated the db to utf8mb4 and I'm still stuck.   The idea is to get the data formatted so I can create a report without using excel to create a pivot table.

Comment: (When you get a little more reputation, you can add comments, answers, and edit your question.)

Comment: I got an idea from the python code I found.  The database appends the question-id to the survey-id for the column names.  The code got the columns from the schema and looped across every row and then down the table. Then I need to look in another table for an ID.  If the ID is a particular ID, I need to get the answer from another table.  I can do this in a programming language but I'm not sure how to do it in MySQL yet.  I'm going to read about loops and cursors now.

Comment: I am ashamed to admit how many days I have been trying to make this work.  The software creates a new table for each survey.  Each question has its own column.  So, I never know how many columns will be added to the table.  I was able to do this with a survey that has 3 questions that I want:   (I wish I could format this better)

Comment: SELECT * FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id,144477X148X741, 741 AS qid, 144477X148X741 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id,144477X148X742SQ001, 742 AS qid, 144477X148X742SQ001 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477
UNION ALL
SELECT id,144477X148X745, 745 AS qid, 144477X148X745 AS value FROM survey_survey_144477;

Comment: select T.id, SQ.question, SQ.type, -- SA.answer,
case SQ.type
when 'L' then SA.answer     -- list choice
-- when 'M' then -- multiple choice
-- when 'B' then -- array-10(B)
   when 'T' OR 'N' then T.value  -- text or numeric
   when 'K' then T.value -- slider 
--    else "Do nothing"
end as 'answer'
   from survey_questions SQ
   join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
   join temp T on T.qid = SQ.qid
       and T.value = SA.code
   where SQ.sid = 144477
     -- and SQ.type = 'K'
   order by T.id;

Comment: But that only gets values that are of type "L".   I need to get the values of type "K" from the Temp table and I have not been able to get it to work yet.  I need to create a case that selects values from one table if L and from another table if K...  etc..   I use to create reports at a former job when the reporting staff got backed up and I could walk over to someones desk for help.  I sure miss having someone to ask.

Comment: My idea is bad because it will have to create a table to look up values but I don't know another way around it.  I'll have duplicate data which seems to be a waste of space.  I don't know about triggers, but from the name,  I assume I can create a trigger that adds the fields to the mapping (temp for now) table when someone answers a survey.   I could also edit the php code to place the data into the tables properly but software updates would cause issues.

Comment: Tip: Study JOINs; avoid Cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need pivoting, I think about doing it in SQL.  But I quickly dismiss the thought as too painful to deal with.  Instead, I write code in PHP to pivot data that is stored is a more "natural" way for databases -- one row per thingie, not one column per thingie.

This should address your one-table-per-survey issue.  It is generally poor design to create tables that rapidly.

That said, I decided to see what it would take to automate the process in SQL.  Still a [*mess*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pivoting-in-mariadb/) .

Comment: Thanks.  I'm reading this page about conditional joins.  I have an error on the line with my IF.  Maybe I should edit the PHP (survey software) to create the proper table?

Comment: select 
    SQ.question,
    SQ.type,
    if (SQ.type = 'L', SQ.type = 'K') as 'answer'  -- ERROR HERE
    from survey_questions SQ
       -- Get answers from survey_answers if type = L
       left join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
           and SQ.type = 'L'
       left join temp T on T.qid = SQ.qid 
           and T.value = SA.code
           and SQ.type = 'L'
       -- Get answers from temp if type = K. 
     left join temp T on T.qid = SQ.qid 
           and SQ.type = 'K'
  where SQ.sid = 144477;

Comment: What is `if (SQ.type = 'L', SQ.type = 'K')` supposed to do?  `IF()` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: It gets the answer from a different table. If K, get it table1...  If L, get the answer from table2.   I might edit the php and create a look-up table.

Comment: `IF` does not work that way.  You might need a `UNION`.  It is messy to pick between two tables.

Comment: I'm close. This will not give me types ('T','N','K', 'S')    select
    SQ.question,
    -- Types ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (SQ.type IN ('B','M','L'), SA.answer, LU2.answer) as 'answer'
    from survey_questions SQ
       left join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
          -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
        join survey_answers_lookup LU on LU.qid = SQ.qid 
           and LU.answer = SA.code
          -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
    left join survey_answers_lookup LU2 on LU2.qid = SQ.qid 
            and SQ.type IN ('T','N','K', 'S')
  where SQ.sid = 144477;

Comment: This one gives me too many if 'type' is in the questions table but not in the lookup table. (B, M, L types)

Comment: select
    SA.code,
    SQ.question,
    SQ.type,
    -- Types can be: ! * 1 E F K L M N Q R S T X Y
    if (SQ.type IN ('B','M','L'), SA.answer, LU2.answer) as 'answer'
    from survey_questions SQ
       left join survey_answers SA on SA.qid = SQ.qid
          -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
        left join survey_answers_lookup LU on LU.qid = SQ.qid 
           and LU.answer = SA.code
          -- and SQ.type IN ('B','M','L')
    left join survey_answers_lookup LU2 on LU2.qid = SQ.qid 
            and SQ.type IN ('T','N','K', 'S')
  where SQ.sid = 144477;

Comment: So I need to get the joins in the condition.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `survey_answers_lookup` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `survey_table_row_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'id that is in the survey_<id> table',
  `answer` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

Comment: Could you summarize your current state and add it to the question?

Comment: I posted my solution at this link.   Thanks for your help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356100/mysql-mariadb-stored-procedure-prepared-statement-union-values-from-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

To try to summarize the problem:

Given these 3 tables,

Questions:

```
select qid, sid, question from survey_questions where sid = 144477;
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| qid | sid    | question                                                                                  |
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 748 | 144477 | Please enter your email address or phone number if you would like someone to contact you. |
| 740 | 144477 | How would you rate our product's quality?                                                 |
| 741 | 144477 | Do you think our product helps your business?                                             |
| 742 | 144477 | One a scale of 1-10, how would you rate the value of our product?                         |
| 743 | 144477 |                                                                                           |
| 745 | 144477 | Will you recommend our product?                                                           |
+-----+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answers lookup (mapping?)

```
select * from survey_answers_lookup;

# id, sid, qid, survey_table_row_id, answer
'1', '144477', '740', '1', '1'
'2', '144477', '741', '1', 'A1'
'3', '144477', '742', '1', '5.0000000000'
'4', '144477', '745', '1', 'A1'
'5', '144477', '748', '1', '1@email.com'
'6', '144477', '740', '2', '2'
'7', '144477', '741', '2', 'A2'
'8', '144477', '742', '2', '8.0000000000'
'9', '144477', '745', '2', 'A2'
'10', '144477', '748', '2', '2@email.com'
'11', '144477', '740', '3', '5'
'12', '144477', '741', '3', 'A2'
'13', '144477', '742', '3', '10.0000000000'
'14', '144477', '745', '3', 'A2'
'15', '144477', '748', '3', '3@email.com'
```

Answers:

```
select * from survey_answers where qid between 740 and 745;
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
| qid | code | answer    | sortorder | assessment_value | language | scale_id |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
| 740 | 1    | Excellent |         1 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 2    | Very good |         2 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 3    | Good      |         3 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 4    | Fair      |         4 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 740 | 5    | Poor      |         5 |                1 | en       |        0 |
| 741 | A1   | Yes       |         1 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 741 | A2   | No        |         2 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 745 | A1   | Yes       |         1 |                0 | en       |        0 |
| 745 | A2   | No        |         2 |                0 | en       |        0 |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

The desired output would be:

```
| How would you rate ... | Do you think our product ... | One a scale of 1-10 ... | Will you recommend |
+-----------------+------+------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Excellent              | Yes                          | 7                       | Yes                |
| Very good              | No                           | 8                       | Yes                |
```

(Opinion: that is unwieldy in width.)

Let's do it in 3 steps:

Step 1: get the data:

```
SELECT  qid, q.question, a.answer
    FROM survey_questions AS q
    JOIN survey_answers_lookup AS al  USING(sid, qid)
    JOIN survey_answers AS a  USING(sid, qid)
    WHERE sid = 144477
      AND al.answer = a.code
    ORDER BY qid;
```

See if that gets the desired output, but not yet pivoted.  When you are happy with that, let's move on to step 2.

Step 2: `CASE WHEN`.  I don't understand what you are talking about -- I don't see it in the tables.

Step 3: Pivot

Make that a subquery to feed to the code generated by

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Thanks.  I got something to work and I posted at the link below but it does not work as expected.  I can't join anything with the survey_survey_144477 table because ....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356100/mysql-mariadb-stored-procedure-prepared-statement-union-values-from-dynamic

Comment: Continued from above: because they created column names from the sid, gid and qid with a X between the numbers.

Comment: The more I hear about this piece of software, the less I like it.  `CONCAT(sid, 'x', qid')` gives you `"144477x741"` -- is that the kind of thing you are looking for?