# Select Data from 2 tables where they extend the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

**My problem is this:**

I have two tables. One that carries the real data and another that is used as a backup. Whenever something gets changed on the real data, a trigger copies the original row into the backup-table.

**What I need is the following:**

I want to select all the original real data. This means all the entries from the real data table which were never changed and all the data from the backup-table which have been inserted the first time.

Imagine these tables:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗ ╔══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ RealId ║ Numeric  ║ ║ BackupId ║ RealId ║ Numeric  ║
╠════════╬══════════╣ ╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║        3 ║ ║        1 ║      1 ║        7 ║
║      2 ║       19 ║ ║        2 ║      1 ║        9 ║
║      3 ║       24 ║ ║        3 ║      1 ║       14 ║
║      4 ║        5 ║ ║        4 ║      2 ║        2 ║
║      5 ║       23 ║ ║        5 ║      3 ║       13 ║
╚════════╩══════════╝ ║        6 ║      5 ║        9 ║
                      ║        7 ║      5 ║        4 ║
                      ╚══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

My goal is to make a query that will return something like this:

```
╔══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ BackupId ║ RealId ║ Numeric  ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ 1        ║      1 ║        7 ║
║ 4        ║      2 ║        2 ║
║ 5        ║      3 ║       13 ║
║ NULL     ║      4 ║        5 ║
║ 6        ║      5 ║        9 ║
╚══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

As you can see, I always want to return the first entry made with a specific Realid from the backup-table. (RealId and BackupId are always unique)

One approach i thought about was

```
SELECT MIN(BackupId), RealId
FROM BackupTable
GROUP BY RealId
```

As for the real-table, I thought about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM real-table A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * 
     FROM backup-table B
     WHERE B.RealId = A.RealId
)
```

But I simply can't think of the right way to combine the tables.

Comment: Think you are pretty much there, but don't use your derived table in an EXISTS, INNER JOIN to it from the real table.

Comment: You have a case where an item exists in the real table, but not backup. Can it also be valid that an item can exist in backup but not real ?

Comment: @SimonB real-table can hold rows with RealId without backup-table to have a row with the same RealId. But backup-table will always have a row with RealId which also exists in real-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
Create table #Real (RealID int, [Numeric] int)

Create table #Backup (BackupID int, RealID int, [Numeric] int)

Insert into #Real values(1, 3)
Insert into #Real values(2, 19)
Insert into #Real values(3, 24)
Insert into #Real values(4, 5)
Insert into #Real values(5, 23)

Insert into #Backup values (1, 1, 7)
Insert into #Backup values (2, 1, 9)
Insert into #Backup values (3, 1, 14)
Insert into #Backup values (4, 2, 2)
Insert into #Backup values (5, 3, 13)
Insert into #Backup values (6, 5, 9)
Insert into #Backup values (7, 5, 4)

Select distinct 
First_Value(b.[BackupID]) over (partition by r.RealID order by b.BackupID) as [BackupID]
    , r.RealID as [RealID]
    , isnull(First_Value(b.[Numeric]) over (partition by r.RealID order by b.BackupID), r.numeric) as [Numeric]
from #Real r 
left join #Backup b on r.realID = b.realid
order by r.[RealID]
```

Comment: How would this extend if the both tables had 20+ columns? [Numeric] was just an example to show, that the data is different

Comment: Add the following to the SELECT for each column: , isnull(First_Value(b.[Col1]) over (partition by r.RealID order by b.BackupID), r.Col1) as [Col1]

Comment: For the given example your answer is correct and also more efficient than the one I made up. Thus, your answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone pre-2012....

(* now edited to assume that all realIDs will exist in the real table)

```
SELECT        
    firstB.minBU AS [first Backup]
    , R.realid
    , ISNULL(B.numeric, R.numeric) AS [original value]
FROM            
    (SELECT realid, MIN(backupid) AS minBU
        FROM test.[backup] AS backup_1 GROUP BY realid
    ) AS firstB 
    INNER JOIN
    test.[backup] AS B 
        ON firstB.realid = B.realid AND firstB.minBU = B.backupid 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        test.real AS R ON firstB.realid = R.realid
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this post on SO:

[Select from table if record found in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310838/select-from-table-if-record-found-in-another-table)

The answer to that question helped me to make up a solution like this:

```
SELECT NULL AS BackupId, A.* FROM real-table A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM backup-table B
    WHERE B.RealId = A.RealId
)

union all

Select C.* FROM backup-table C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(BackupId) AS BackupId, 
           RealId
        FROM backup-table 
        GROUP BY RealId 
    ) D
on D.BackupId = C.BackupId

ORDER BY RealId Asc
```

However, I would like to test this against cloudsafes answer, to see which has better performance.

Comment: Execution plans are here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJSueThnZ
 36% vs 64%

Comment: For multiple numeric columns, the solution you provided will be better.